# Split a domain and migrate change to database

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have a domain class and it already has a lot of data in the database. Now I need to split the domain into two. Is there a way by which the data in the database will automatically be split into the two tables as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Grails Database Migration Plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-database-migration/) plugin for such a task.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no automatic mechanism for your issue. i would backup the old database schema, change the domain class schema, deploy the new shema (hopefully all database changes get executed) and migrate the old data to the new schema.